# C# - Microsoft Expression Encoder missing reference, how to add them to project?

Tags: c#, reference, image-capture, expression-encoder

I have an application that has an Image Capture feature.

When I try to build it in Visual Studio 2012, I get missing references to Expression Encoder. The image capture facility has been achieved using Microsoft Expression Encoder, and it uses code from it's API. In order to build this application successfully, the PC where I'm trying to build needs some sort of Expression Encoder codec where it will get the references from.

I have tried installing the full application (Microsoft Expression Encoder 4) which is about 25MB, which fixes all the references. We do not want that, due to the application being offered to clients, which means they will have to install another application, the Expression Encoder 4 on top of our application. I'm thinking that there must be a codec of some sort that contains these missing references which is of course smaller than 25MB.

The missing references are the following:

Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.Devices;
Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.Live;
LiveJob
LiveDeviceSource
EncoderDevices
EncoderDeviceType
EncoderDevice
Source Properties
Preview Window

Does anyone have more experience with this and knows how to fix the missing references?

Thank you very much.

Comment: After Steward Mbofana (below) suggested, I added the dll file as a reference as you suggested. It fixed the missing references but when trying to actually use the image capture facility, it was throwing an error about Encoder.Utilities, and Encoder Types. To fix this error, I added the other 3 dlls in the folder as a reference: Encoder.Api2, Encoder.Types and Encoder.Utilities. This caused the application to give me another error: "The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.SkuManager' threw an
exception.". Do you know what this error could mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible to deploy an application that uses EE4 SDK without installing the entire application on the target machine. Things had to change from EE3 to EE4 but it does not. Even if you try to "copy local" DLLs in your application location, it requires to install the 25MB EE4 application.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Sergiu Tripon could you indicate if it helped ?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an article that shows workarounds for missing Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.resources.dll file, I was able to get through all exceptions using it, but got stuck on 'Appliation not licensed. To fix, install and run application.'
Link to article:
http://uprightbassics.blogspot.com/2014/01/how-to-deploy-expression-encoder-4-sdk.html

Comment: Following the steps in the article worked for me: I no longer need to install Expression Encoder to use the SDK. Unfortunately changes to the registry are needed which is not an option on our clients.

Comment: It is only necessary to run as Admin the first time the application runs, this workaround has worked for me, saving the hassle of installing Expression Encoder.

Answer (score 0):

Add reference to

microsoft.expression.encoder.dll

Check in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Expression\Encorder 4

If possible copy the dll into your project and change the property Copy To Output to Copy Always.

Comment: Hi, I added the dll file as a reference as you suggested. It fixed the missing references but when trying to actually use the image capture facility, it was throwing an error about Encoder.Utilities, and Encoder Types. To fix this error, I added the other 3 dlls in the folder as a reference: Encoder.Api2, Encoder.Types and Encoder.Utilities. This caused the application to give me another error: "The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.SkuManager' threw an
exception.". Do you know what this error could mean?

Comment: It might be licensing issue check http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/expression/en-US/7e4468a6-ebe0-49af-8500-1f8cdf74a4dc/microsoftexpressionencoderskumanager-exception?forum=encoder

Comment: Hi Stewart, I have looked at the forum, but the person writing there is suggesting the following: "Do you have Encoder installed on the target system? (Just copying the DLL's across won't be enough)". This is the thing that we are trying to avoid, having to install the full Expression Encoder application. Do you know if that is possible? Thank you very much for your help.